# Undefined index: name (Import list) Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, import

i am doing a project using Laravel, and I trying make an import list (csv), like in this video:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PrjuwU-Xu7A&t=243s

I think, it is almost done the import list page; but keep giving this error: **Undefined index: name**

Probably the problem is here:

**CsvImport.php:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Imports;

use App\Product;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToModel;

class CsvImport implements ToModel
{
    /**
    * @param array $row
    *
    * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|null
    */
    public function model(array $row)
    {
        return new product([
            'name'          => $row["name"],
            'description'   => $row["description"],
            'category'      => $row["category"],
            'price'         => $row["price"],
            'user_id'       => $row["user_id"],


        ]);
    }
}
```

**web.php**

```
Route::get('/csv_file', 'CsvFile@index');

Route::post('csv_file/import', 'CsvFile@csv_import')->name('import');
```

My database (table) call product. I am following exactly the video.
Please help me.

Comment: What does your CSV file look like?

Comment: @James https://www.dropbox.com/s/6y9gm7wfdcwj7jo/Screenshot%202020-06-09%2017.55.05.png?dl=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make sure your Excel file has `name` in header.
Also, you can acheive the same with just

```php
    public function model(array $row)
    {
        return new product($row);
    }
```

Comment: @seique3, You can define a heading row in CSV as a first row in your file `name;description;category;price;user_id`. If that doesn't help, try to import with `$row[0]`, instead of `$row['name']`. If that doesn't work... use Excel file instead of CSV :)

Comment: do you have another ideia?

Comment: Can you post the error you see when you try $row[0] approach?

Comment: ErrorException
Undefined offset: 2

Comment: can you say your email to me and you can talk? please

Comment: @seique3 my email will not speed things up :) Can you post your CSV you are trying to process. You can upload it to https://gist.github.com/

Comment: https://gist.github.com/seijikiy/574123160b47597d298f17418df0e4f7       (I put 2 example what i was trying, but i did a lot tests)

Comment: Can you post the output of `public function model(array $row)
    {
       dd($row);
    }`?

Comment: what is output ?

Comment: are you talk about this: array:2 [▼
  0 => "name"
  1 => "Import"
]

Comment: Here is your answer to your question :D It reads your file vertically and not horizontally.

Comment: so, if i use  return new product([
            'name'          => $row["name"],
            'description'   => $row["description"],
            'category'      => $row["category"],
            'price'         => $row["price"],
            'user_id'       => $row["user_id"],              will work??? but i need use vertical row?

Comment: Your problem is different. The file is being read like this : 0.name, Import; 1.description, This is description etc. There might be plugin misconfiguration.

Comment: See https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/custom-csv-settings.html#available-settings. Try setting `'delimiter' => ';'`

Answer (score 0):

Import this

```
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadingRow;
```

and also implement it like this:

```
class UsersImport implements ToModel, WithHeadingRow
{

}
```

**This work for me !**

What I understood from this is that you didn't specify how to read keys from csv file (i.e Read key from row or column), laravel does not know where to get `name` from that's why its giving undefined index